# How can I calculate the number of objects that heap memory will hold?

Tags: java, algorithm, control-structure

I want to code/design an algorithm in java in which i started with an input of

`variable int i=0;`

`while (i==0){i==1;}`

create or start again with var i in new memory location set value again to 1;
loop to assign value 1 to var and jump to next memory location.
until heap memory full
 then Calculate total variables created and exist in memory , by using loop

`System.out.println(total var created);`

Can i done this in Java?

i have done with "how much time to create fixed variable count in java"

Comment: No, you can't do this.  The loop will not create new variables each time; it will reuse the old ones.

Comment: ok! then how i can do this?

Comment: We still can't tell what you want to do.  If you just want to fill memory, create a linked list and keep adding to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to fill the heap memory. I guess creating String literals in a loop will do that;

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 1000){

    System.out.println("2 times" + i + "equals" + i * 2);
    i = i + 1;
}
```

will create 1000 string literals in the constant string pool. These literals will not be canditates to be garbage collected for some time -enough for filling the memory- for purposes of reuse. So they will fill up the memory eventually. If you increase value 1000, you'll get more literals.

[For further reading, here's a blog post](http://www.javaarch.info/dont-fill-memory-strings-java-string-string-constant-pool/)

Comment: your program prints this:   2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0
2 times0equals0                  i added this line in while loop: i=i+1;            now it prints:              2 times1equals2
2 times2equals4

......................................
2 times999equals1998
2 times1000equals2000

Comment: i want to allocate value to var. var have to store every value which initialized by loop on every cycle and values/vars have to remain in memory, loop has to run until memory full and i will get total count of variables which occupied on heap memory..

Comment: Alright it seems my answer doesn't fulfill your requirements. As long as you use the same variable i, you wont get an increasing number of variables, so I can't figure out another solution. Anyway I won't delete my post to keep your question popular. Maybe somebody solves your problem.